# Scala varargs syntax

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

Suppose I have a method like this:

```scala
def func(strs: String*) = {
    //Do something
}
```

That means that the function can take an undefined number of strings as arguments, right? Then, why can I do this

```scala
func("hello", "world")
```

or this

```scala
val strArr = Array("hello", "world")
func(str: _*)
```

but not this?

```scala
val strArr = Array("hello", "world")
func("foo", strArr: _*)
```

Comment: Because, that's how scala syntax specifies it ...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be asking about reasoning behind language a particular language design decision rather than for help with a specific programming problem.

Comment: @Dima although you are right, the question would now be, is there a workaround for  this?

Comment: `func(("foo" +: strArr) : _*)`

Comment: design-wise, see commentary at https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/4181